# Why const sheet = excel.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet(); return null in JADE in excel online?

Tags: javascript, excel, jade4j

I'm new to JADE. Additionally, although I have learned JavaScript before, I have not used it for a while, until I want to do some task in Excel. The reason that I want to do some task automatically by JADE in Excel instead of other tools or programming languages (such as VBA), because in online version, I have not found the such thing.

Why does the statement

```
const sheet = excel.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
```

return `null` in JADE in excel online?

Code 1.1

```
async function write_timestamp(excel){
    const sheet = excel.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    var range='';
    range = sheet.getRange("A1");
  Jade.print("Hello World!!!");
  //Jade.print(JSON.stringify(sheet));  
  
  Jade.print("Get type of Sheet class!!!"); 
  Jade.print(typeof(sheet));
  Jade.print("Get Sheet!!!"); 
  Jade.print(sheet);
  
  Jade.print("Get type of Range class!!!"); 
}
```

---

Output:
[image: Output of Code 1.1]

---

What I tried:

Look at these manuals.
[Microsoft Javascript Excel API/Excel.Worksheet class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheet?view=excel-js-preview)

[The developers blog](https://support.jsvba.com/?introduction)